# Techniques for Calling into a WCF Service from Java

Tags: java, .net, wcf

Besides using Web Services, or POX (or custom HTTP), are there some other techniques that I could utilize for calling services exposed from WCF via ___________ to the Java world?  These requests will be in the same machine.  Maybe RAW TCP/IP?

I'm just inquiring for a project that we need to possible provide some method of calling synchronous code in the .NET world and return results to our Java world.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To talk with a Java client you'll have to use one of the interoperable protocols which limits you to going across HTTP or HTTPS.  TCP can only be used between clients running Windows on an intranet.  Even on the same machine you won't be able to use Named Pipes either for the same reason.

The interoperable protocols are covered in Chapter 1 of "[Programming WCF Services](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521301/index.html)" by Juval Lowy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following project http://iiop-net.sourceforge.net/